# How to create empty collection in magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, collection

Cannot find it anywhere.

Basically, I try to pass empty collection to my view if query parameters are not sufficient without actually querying database. I mean for example if my custom search requires parameter `s` to have more than three characters. If parameter is shorter I can return empty collection.

I don't want to do stupid thing like adding where statements like `entity_id==1 && entity_id1!=1`

Answer (score 2):

Every Magento 2 collection extend `\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection` so you can do:

```
new \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection();
```

To create a new empty collection.

PS: do use instantiate the new collection directly like, use DI to inject the class ;)

Comment: Yep, kind of stupid question then. Did not think it's so simple.

Comment: Just to add for someone who will try to copy that directly. You don't actually use new Collection. You should use DI. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html .

Comment: @MaciejPaprocki of course, updated the answer to clarify that

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Moazzam\ManageModels\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface as ResultInterfaceAlias;
use Moazzam\ManageModels\Model\PetFactory;
use Moazzam\ManageModels\Model\ResourceModel\Pet\CollectionFactory;

/**
 * Render the json data from the collection of pets
 *
 * Class Index
 */
class Index implements HttpGetActionInterface, HttpPostActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ResultFactory
     */
    private ResultFactory $resultFactory;
    /**
     * @var PetFactory
     */
    private PetFactory $petFactory;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    private CollectionFactory $petCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param ResultFactory $resultFactory
     * @param CollectionFactory $petCollectionFactory
     * @param PetFactory $petFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ResultFactory $resultFactory,
        CollectionFactory $petCollectionFactory,
        PetFactory $petFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
        $this->petFactory=$petFactory;
        $this->petCollectionFactory=$petCollectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Filter the record through the addFieldToFiler and return in json format
     *
     * @return ResultInterfaceAlias
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $petCollection = $this->petCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('pet_type', ['eq' => 'Cat']);
        $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        $resultJson->setData($petCollection->getData());
        return $resultJson;
    }
}
```